# Countdown Timer in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating an Access DB which needs to auto refresh every 300 seconds via a Macro. The Form contains two text boxes called:
1) REFRESH_INTERVAL (here the interval can be changed)
2) COUNTER (this field should show the count down)

When the DB is opened, the MACRO (M_RUN ALL MACROS) should run the first time.
When done the count down needs to start.
Once it has reached 0 the Macro (M_RUN ALL MACROS) should run again.
Once completed the count down should restart again at 300 seconds and the process should repeat itself.
If The Field REFRESH_INTERVAL is changed, the countdown should start at that number.

If have found several pieces of tips checking the web, but did not manage to fit the pieces to one working piece.
Who can help?

Comment: You're going to want to look at the OnTimer event of the form.  Microsoft's official page for it sucks, this page at least gives a working example: http://www.blueclaw-db.com/access_event_programming/timer.htm

Comment: Got the On Timer working with an interval of 5 minutes. However I want to have the countdown visible in the Form. That is why I created 2 text boxes to have it shown and to have the interval time adjusted (when needed).

Answer (score 1):

This response assumes you're able to get the user's input with respect to the timer event.  What I propose is you set a timer event to the frequency you want your count-down timer to refresh.  Using public variables you can keep a running sum of the intervals that have passed, and when that cumulative time surpasses the refresh interval, run your macro and reset the public variable keeping track of the cumulative sum of time.  I've set the refresh rate at 1 second, but depending on what you're doing this can be really obnoxious to users trying to interact with other forms.

Basically what you're doing here is creating a `Form_Load` event to set the timer interval (default to 1 second (1000 milliseconds) and to set the overall number of seconds you want to count down from until the macro is run.

Also an `AfterUpdate` event on your `REFRESH_INTERVAL` textbox is run if the user decides to change the refresh interval.

Finally a `Form_Timer` event that monitors time past and will run the macro and reset the timer once the cumulative time surpasses the `REFRESH_INTERVAL`.

```
Option Compare Database
Public lTimer As Long
Public lTimeTotal As Long


Private Sub Form_Load()
If IsNull(Me.REFRESH_INTERVAL) Then
    Me.TimerInterval = 1000
    Me.lTimeTotal = 300000
Else
    Me.TimerInterval = Me.REFRESH_INTERVAL * 1000
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()

lTimer = lTimer + Me.TimerInterval

If lTimer >= lTimeTotal Then
    DoCmd.RunMacro "M_RUN ALL MACROS"
    Me.COUNTER = 0
    Me.COUNTER = lTimeTotal / 1000 & " Seconds Remaining..."
Else
    Me.COUNTER = Int((lTimeTotal - lTimer) / 1000) & " Seconds Remaining..."
End If
DoEvents
End Sub


Private Sub REFRESH_INTERVAL_AfterUpdate()
lTimeTotal = Me.REFRESH_INTERVAL * 1000
End Sub
```