# Countdown with TimerInterval in VBA for MSAccess

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want a timer that counts down from say, 05:00, or 5 minutes.

This countdown happens near instantaneously rather than one second increments.

I added the `debug.print` to confirm that the interval was set at 1000 milliseconds. Note, X is set to `1` elsewhere in the code.

```vb
Sub Form_Timer()
    
    Do While Me.DisplayTimer > Format(TimeSerial(0, 0, 0), "nn:ss")
        Debug.Print Me.TimerInterval
        
        Me.DisplayTimer = Format((CountDownTime - 1.15740740740741E-05 * X), "nn:ss")
        X = X + 1
            
    Loop
                      
    Forms!TimerLogF.TimerInterval = 0
    Call LogProcess
            
End Sub
```

Comment: `Me.DisplayTimer > Format(TimeSerial(0, 0, 0), "nn:ss")` <-- This does not do what you think it does: it compares **strings**, not time-span values - and strings have different comparison semantics to temporal values.

Comment: @Dai So I need to make Do while evaluation a timeSerial to timeSerial evaluation correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Countdown Timer in MS-Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960111/countdown-timer-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1):

Always handle date and time as *Date*.

Also, the form and the timer interval *is* the loop. So:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Timer()

    ' Me!DisplayTimer holds, say, "5:00".
    ' Me!DisplayTimer has the property Format set to: n:ss
    ' Me.TimerInterval property is set to, say, 1000.

    Dim ThisTime    As Date

    ThisTime = TimeValue(Me!DisplayTimer.Value)
    ThisTime = DateAdd("s", -Me.TimerInterval / 1000, ThisTime)
    Me!DisplayTimer.Value = ThisTime
    
    If ThisTime <= TimeSerial(0, 0, 0) Then
        Me.TimerInterval = 0
        Call LogProcess
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you appear to just be overwriting `ThisTime`.  Is that intentional?  Also why are you dividing `Me.TimerInterval by 1000?

Comment: Yes, to improve readability. `TimerInterval` is milliseconds, and we need a one second decrement.

Comment: I have completely changed the code to be very simple, and something is still wrong with the counter.  I removed all of the complication of timers and just set two variables, and it's still counting down instantaneously.    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim Z As Integer
    
    Y = 50
    Z = 0
    
    Do While Y > Z
        
        Me.DisplayTimer = Y
        Y = Y - 1
        
    Loop

I even set the interval to 1000 within that sub.  For some reason, it's not looping in 1 second increments.

Comment: That's why I provided code that runs as intended. Again, Timer runs the loop.